# How to change and print multiple filters of a single pivot table at once?

Tags: excel, vba

### Overview:

I have a pivottable with filter. The filter contains a list from 1 to 30, each of which must be printed separately. That is, each time I have to change the filter and print the filtered result.

### My demand:

What I want is to print all of them at once.

### Conditions:

The list of numbers is not continous or static. It means that some numbers are droped and some new numbers may be added later.

### My Current Situation and Challange:

By means of macro recorder command, I could arrive up to the following situation. But the problem is that, I don't know how to make it dynamic. I mean, how to say "do the procedure for the existing numbers".

**Can anyone help me please to correct and complete the following macro?**

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'     
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Leistungsnachweise").PivotFields("Tour").CurrentPage _ = "1"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _ IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Leistungsnachweise").PivotFields("Tour").CurrentPage _ = "2"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _ IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Dio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me a clear-cut answer in the following link. I found it useful, so I share it with you.

[You can find it in the Ozgrid Forum](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=200437&p=773766)

**Here is a copy of the answer:**

```
Sub LoopField() 
Dim pivF As PivotField 
Dim pivI As PivotItem 

Set pivF = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Leistungsnachweise").PivotFields("Tour")  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
For Each pivI In pivF.PivotItems 
    pivF.CurrentPage = pivI.Name 

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False 
Next pivI 
 'Clear filer
pivF.ClearAllFilters 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```